# UVa excercise 11799 reports Runtime Error

Tags: c++

I am making an exercise (https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=2899&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+22762175) on UVa online judge. My code works fine on my computer, but when I submit my code, it reports me a Runtime error. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int t;
int n = 50;
int speed;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::cin >> t;
    int data[t][n] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        std::cin >> n;
        data[i][0] = n;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            std::cin >> data[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        speed = 0;      
        for (int j = 1; j <= data[i][0]; j++) {
            if (data[i][j] > speed) {
                speed = data[i][j];
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Case " << i+1 << ": " << speed << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `int data[t][n] = {0};` is not allowed per the c++ standard, variable lenght arrays are supported by some compilers as an extension

Comment: plus: arrays are `0` based indexed, ie your loop goes out of bounds

Comment: dont get mislead into thinking online judges are a good way to learn the basics of the language, take a look here instead if you want to learn something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list